# How to reduce empty borders in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, border, whitespace, edit, removing-whitespace

A PDF with lecture slides contains huge whitespaces (ca. 50% of actual slide dimensions on each border). How can I get rid of those?

[image]

Source: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kyros/courses/418/Lectures/lecture.2010f.02.pdf

Comment: In which programming language do you want to implement that? With which PDF library? How far did you get in trying? What stopped you?

Comment: Thanks, I have found a workaround. I thought PDFs are kind of like software compilations, i.e. you can look at them, but not edit them.

Comment: **Solution**: There are online tools for cropping PDFs. I used https://www.sejda.com/de/crop-pdf